# Check if an object is empty and with undefined properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to check the below,

```
USECASE: 1
var obj = {};
_.isEmpty(obj); ====> returns true 

USECASE: 2
var obj = { model: undefined, vendor: undefined, type: undefined }
_.isEmpty(obj); ====> returns false
```

In usecase 2 is there any other function that i could leverage to return true since all the properties are undefined.

I referred this http://www.ericfeminella.com/blog/2012/08/18/determining-if-an-object-is-empty-with-underscore-lo-dash/ but not sure how to implement it without modifying the native method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**every**](http://underscorejs.org/#every) and pass in the [**isUndefined**](http://underscorejs.org/#isUndefined) predicate:

```
var obj = { model: undefined, vendor: undefined, type: undefined }

var result = _.every(obj, _.isUndefined);
```

Alternatively you could [**omit**](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) the undefined values and check whether the object is empty:

```
var result = _.isEmpty(_.omit(obj, _.isUndefined));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without Underscore:

```
const objEmpty = obj => Object.keys(obj).every(key => obj[key] === undefined);
```

Will accept an object and return true if the object is empty (no properties) or if all the properties have `undefined` value. Else returns false.

Comment: i'm pretty new with ECMA stuffs, can you please elaborate a little about how i can invoke this function

Comment: That'll only give enumerable properties, which may be OK.  `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` if the OP needs all, and `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()` to include ES6 symbols.

Comment: @Sai Like so: `objEmpty(obj)` or `objEmpty({foo: undefined})`